# Pod's state "pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims" when deploy Jenkins with Helm chart

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, deployment, helm

I try to deploy Jenkins in local Kubernetes cluster with Helm from repo stable/jenkins:lts. But after deployment I get pod which has status "`pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims`". PVC has status "bound" without any errors.

My environment: virtual machine with Linux Ubuntu 18.x where there is installed microk8s. When I deploy I change only node type and persistence size.

Helm chart config:

```
NAME:   inclined-eagle
REVISION: 1
RELEASED: Fri Jan 11 21:35:47 2019
CHART: jenkins-0.28.6
USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
Master:
  ServiceType: NodePort
Persistence:
  Size: 4Gi

COMPUTED VALUES:
Agent:
  AlwaysPullImage: false
  Component: jenkins-slave
  CustomJenkinsLabels: []
  Enabled: true
  Image: jenkins/jnlp-slave
  ImageTag: 3.27-1
  NodeSelector: {}
  PodRetention: Never
  Privileged: false
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 200m
      memory: 256Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 200m
      memory: 256Mi
  volumes: null
Master:
  AdditionalConfig: {}
  AdminUser: admin
  CLI: false
  CSRF:
    DefaultCrumbIssuer:
      Enabled: true
      ProxyCompatability: true
  Component: jenkins-master
  CustomConfigMap: false
  DisabledAgentProtocols:
  - JNLP-connect
  - JNLP2-connect
  ExtraPorts: null
  HealthProbeLivenessFailureThreshold: 12
  HealthProbeReadinessPeriodSeconds: 10
  HealthProbes: true
  HealthProbesLivenessTimeout: 90
  HealthProbesReadinessTimeout: 60
  HostNetworking: false
  Image: jenkins/jenkins
  ImagePullPolicy: Always
  ImageTag: lts
  Ingress:
    Annotations: {}
    ApiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    TLS: null
  InitScripts: null
  InstallPlugins:
  - kubernetes:1.14.0
  - workflow-job:2.31
  - workflow-aggregator:2.6
  - credentials-binding:1.17
  - git:3.9.1
  LoadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - 0.0.0.0/0
  Name: jenkins-master
  NodeSelector: {}
  NumExecutors: 0
  OverwriteConfig: false
  PodAnnotations: {}
  ServiceAnnotations: {}
  ServiceLabels: {}
  ServicePort: 8080
  ServiceType: NodePort
  SlaveListenerPort: 50000
  SlaveListenerServiceAnnotations: {}
  SlaveListenerServiceType: ClusterIP
  Tolerations: {}
  UsePodSecurityContext: true
  UseSecurity: true
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 2000m
      memory: 2048Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 50m
      memory: 256Mi
NetworkPolicy:
  ApiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  Enabled: false
Persistence:
  AccessMode: ReadWriteOnce
  Annotations: {}
  Enabled: true
  Size: 4Gi
  mounts: null
  volumes: null
backup:
  annotations:
    iam.amazonaws.com/role: jenkins
  destination: s3://nuvo-jenkins-data/backup
  enabled: false
  env:
  - name: AWS_REGION
    value: us-east-1
  extraArgs: []
  image:
    repository: nuvo/kube-tasks
    tag: 0.1.2
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 1
      memory: 1Gi
    requests:
      cpu: 1
      memory: 1Gi
  schedule: 0 2 * * *
rbac:
  install: false
  roleBindingKind: ClusterRoleBinding
  roleKind: ClusterRole
  roleRef: cluster-admin
  serviceAccountName: default

HOOKS:
---
# inclined-eagle-ui-test-1mhfp
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: "inclined-eagle-ui-test-1mhfp"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": test-success
spec:
  initContainers:
    - name: "test-framework"
      image: "dduportal/bats:0.4.0"
      command:
      - "bash"
      - "-c"
      - |
        set -ex
        # copy bats to tools dir
        cp -R /usr/local/libexec/ /tools/bats/
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /tools
        name: tools
  containers:
    - name: inclined-eagle-ui-test
      image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
      command: ["/tools/bats/bats", "-t", "/tests/run.sh"]
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /tests
        name: tests
        readOnly: true
      - mountPath: /tools
        name: tools
  volumes:
  - name: tests
    configMap:
      name: inclined-eagle-jenkins-tests
  - name: tools
    emptyDir: {}
  restartPolicy: Never
MANIFEST:

---
# Source: jenkins/templates/secret.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: inclined-eagle-jenkins
  labels:
    app: inclined-eagle-jenkins
    chart: "jenkins-0.28.6"
    release: "inclined-eagle"
    heritage: "Tiller"
type: Opaque
data:

  jenkins-admin-password: "enkyZlZqdVdqMw=="

  jenkins-admin-user: "YWRtaW4="
---
# Source: jenkins/templates/config.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: inclined-eagle-jenkins
data:
  config.xml: |-
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <hudson>
      <disabledAdministrativeMonitors/>
      <version>lts</version>
      <numExecutors>0</numExecutors>
      <mode>NORMAL</mode>
      <useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
      <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy">
        <denyAnonymousReadAccess>true</denyAnonymousReadAccess>
      </authorizationStrategy>
      <securityRealm class="hudson.security.LegacySecurityRealm"/>
      <disableRememberMe>false</disableRememberMe>
      <projectNamingStrategy class="jenkins.model.ProjectNamingStrategy$DefaultProjectNamingStrategy"/>
      <workspaceDir>${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}</workspaceDir>
      <buildsDir>${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds</buildsDir>
      <markupFormatter class="hudson.markup.EscapedMarkupFormatter"/>
      <jdks/>
      <viewsTabBar class="hudson.views.DefaultViewsTabBar"/>
      <myViewsTabBar class="hudson.views.DefaultMyViewsTabBar"/>
      <clouds>
        <org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud plugin="kubernetes@1.14.0">
          <name>kubernetes</name>
          <templates>
            <org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.PodTemplate>
              <inheritFrom></inheritFrom>
              <name>default</name>
              <instanceCap>2147483647</instanceCap>
              <idleMinutes>0</idleMinutes>
              <label>inclined-eagle-jenkins-slave </label>
              <nodeSelector></nodeSelector>
                <nodeUsageMode>NORMAL</nodeUsageMode>
              <volumes>
              </volumes>
              <containers>
                <org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.ContainerTemplate>
                  <name>jnlp</name>
                  <image>jenkins/jnlp-slave:3.27-1</image>
                  <privileged>false</privileged>
                  <alwaysPullImage>false</alwaysPullImage>
                  <workingDir>/home/jenkins</workingDir>
                  <command></command>
                  <args>${computer.jnlpmac} ${computer.name}</args>
                  <ttyEnabled>false</ttyEnabled>
                  # Resources configuration is a little hacky. This was to prevent breaking
                  # changes, and should be cleanned up in the future once everybody had
                  # enough time to migrate.
                  <resourceRequestCpu>200m</resourceRequestCpu>
                  <resourceRequestMemory>256Mi</resourceRequestMemory>
                  <resourceLimitCpu>200m</resourceLimitCpu>
                  <resourceLimitMemory>256Mi</resourceLimitMemory>
                  <envVars>
                    <org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.ContainerEnvVar>
                      <key>JENKINS_URL</key>
                      <value>http://inclined-eagle-jenkins:8080</value>
                    </org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.ContainerEnvVar>
                  </envVars>
                </org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.ContainerTemplate>
              </containers>
              <envVars/>
              <annotations/>
              <imagePullSecrets/>
              <nodeProperties/>
              <podRetention class="org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pod.retention.Default"/>
            </org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.PodTemplate></templates>
          <serverUrl>https://kubernetes.default</serverUrl>
          <skipTlsVerify>false</skipTlsVerify>
          <namespace>default</namespace>
          <jenkinsUrl>http://inclined-eagle-jenkins:8080</jenkinsUrl>
          <jenkinsTunnel>inclined-eagle-jenkins-agent:50000</jenkinsTunnel>
          <containerCap>10</containerCap>
          <retentionTimeout>5</retentionTimeout>
          <connectTimeout>0</connectTimeout>
          <readTimeout>0</readTimeout>
          <podRetention class="org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pod.retention.Never"/>
        </org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud>
      </clouds>
      <quietPeriod>5</quietPeriod>
      <scmCheckoutRetryCount>0</scmCheckoutRetryCount>
      <views>
        <hudson.model.AllView>
          <owner class="hudson" reference="../../.."/>
          <name>All</name>
          <filterExecutors>false</filterExecutors>
          <filterQueue>false</filterQueue>
          <properties class="hudson.model.View$PropertyList"/>
        </hudson.model.AllView>
      </views>
      <primaryView>All</primaryView>
      <slaveAgentPort>50000</slaveAgentPort>
      <disabledAgentProtocols>
        <string>JNLP-connect</string>
        <string>JNLP2-connect</string>
      </disabledAgentProtocols>
      <label></label>
      <crumbIssuer class="hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer">
        <excludeClientIPFromCrumb>true</excludeClientIPFromCrumb>
      </crumbIssuer>
      <nodeProperties/>
      <globalNodeProperties/>
      <noUsageStatistics>true</noUsageStatistics>
    </hudson>
  jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration.xml: |-
    <?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration>
      <adminAddress></adminAddress>
      <jenkinsUrl>http://inclined-eagle-jenkins:8080</jenkinsUrl>
    </jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration>
  jenkins.CLI.xml: |-
    <?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <jenkins.CLI>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </jenkins.CLI>
  apply_config.sh: |-
    mkdir -p /usr/share/jenkins/ref/secrets/;
    echo "false" > /usr/share/jenkins/ref/secrets/slave-to-master-security-kill-switch;
    yes n | cp -i /var/jenkins_config/config.xml /var/jenkins_home;
    yes n | cp -i /var/jenkins_config/jenkins.CLI.xml /var/jenkins_home;
    yes n | cp -i /var/jenkins_config/jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration.xml /var/jenkins_home;
    # Install missing plugins
    cp /var/jenkins_config/plugins.txt /var/jenkins_home;
    rm -rf /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins/*.lock
    /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh `echo $(cat /var/jenkins_home/plugins.txt)`;
    # Copy plugins to shared volume
    yes n | cp -i /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins/* /var/jenkins_plugins/;
  plugins.txt: |-
    kubernetes:1.14.0
    workflow-job:2.31
    workflow-aggregator:2.6
    credentials-binding:1.17
    git:3.9.1
---
# Source: jenkins/templates/test-config.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: inclined-eagle-jenkins-tests
data:
  run.sh: |-
    @test "Testing Jenkins UI is accessible" {
      curl --retry 48 --retry-delay 10 inclined-eagle-jenkins:8080/login
    }
---
# Source: jenkins/templates/home-pvc.yaml
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: inclined-eagle-jenkins
  labels:
    app: inclined-eagle-jenkins
    chart: "jenkins-0.28.6"
    release: "inclined-eagle"
    heritage: "Tiller"
spec:
  accessModes:
    - "ReadWriteOnce"
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: "4Gi"
---
# Source: jenkins/templates/jenkins-agent-svc.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: inclined-eagle-jenkins-agent
  labels:
    app: inclined-eagle-jenkins
    chart: "jenkins-0.28.6"
    component: "inclined-eagle-jenkins-master"
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 50000
      targetPort: 50000

      name: slavelistener
  selector:
    component: "inclined-eagle-jenkins-master"
  type: ClusterIP
---
# Source: jenkins/templates/jenkins-master-svc.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: inclined-eagle-jenkins
  labels:
    app: inclined-eagle-jenkins
    heritage: "Tiller"
    release: "inclined-eagle"
    chart: "jenkins-0.28.6"
    component: "inclined-eagle-jenkins-master"
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      name: http
      targetPort: 8080

  selector:
    component: "inclined-eagle-jenkins-master"
  type: NodePort
---
# Source: jenkins/templates/jenkins-master-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: inclined-eagle-jenkins
  labels:
    heritage: "Tiller"
    release: "inclined-eagle"
    chart: "jenkins-0.28.6"
    component: "inclined-eagle-jenkins-master"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: "inclined-eagle-jenkins-master"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: inclined-eagle-jenkins
        heritage: "Tiller"
        release: "inclined-eagle"
        chart: "jenkins-0.28.6"
        component: "inclined-eagle-jenkins-master"
      annotations:
        checksum/config: 4eebbff9187d5eadf249ff0106423ec0b571659e014ed75f2abef5619afc24f9
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
      serviceAccountName: "default"
      initContainers:
        - name: "copy-default-config"
          image: "jenkins/jenkins:lts"
          imagePullPolicy: "Always"
          command: [ "sh", "/var/jenkins_config/apply_config.sh" ]
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 2000m
              memory: 2048Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 256Mi

          volumeMounts:
            -
              mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
              name: jenkins-home
            -
              mountPath: /var/jenkins_config
              name: jenkins-config
            -
              mountPath: /var/jenkins_plugins
              name: plugin-dir
            -
              mountPath: /usr/share/jenkins/ref/secrets/
              name: secrets-dir
      containers:
        - name: inclined-eagle-jenkins
          image: "jenkins/jenkins:lts"
          imagePullPolicy: "Always"
          args: [ "--argumentsRealm.passwd.$(ADMIN_USER)=$(ADMIN_PASSWORD)",  "--argumentsRealm.roles.$(ADMIN_USER)=admin"]
          env:
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: ""
            - name: JENKINS_OPTS
              value: ""
            - name: ADMIN_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: inclined-eagle-jenkins
                  key: jenkins-admin-password
            - name: ADMIN_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: inclined-eagle-jenkins
                  key: jenkins-admin-user
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              name: http
            - containerPort: 50000
              name: slavelistener
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: "/login"
              port: http
            initialDelaySeconds: 90
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            failureThreshold: 12
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: "/login"
              port: http
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 10
          # Resources configuration is a little hacky. This was to prevent breaking
          # changes, and should be cleanned up in the future once everybody had
          # enough time to migrate.
          resources:

            limits:
              cpu: 2000m
              memory: 2048Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 256Mi


          volumeMounts:
            -
              mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
              name: jenkins-home
              readOnly: false
            -
              mountPath: /var/jenkins_config
              name: jenkins-config
              readOnly: true
            -
              mountPath: /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins/
              name: plugin-dir
              readOnly: false
            -
              mountPath: /usr/share/jenkins/ref/secrets/
              name: secrets-dir
              readOnly: false
      volumes:
      - name: jenkins-config
        configMap:
          name: inclined-eagle-jenkins
      - name: plugin-dir
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: secrets-dir
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: jenkins-home
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: inclined-eagle-jenkins
```

pod's log:

```
container "inclined-eagle-jenkins" in pod "inclined-eagle-jenkins-65c8f989d-lglfc" is waiting to start: PodInitializing
```

There is also warning message among events:

```
AssumePod failed: pod 6bf15a11-168a-11e9-b322-0800277359c7 is in the cache, so can't be assumed
```

Comment: Could you add the modified helm chart you try to deploy and add the log?

Comment: Same problem with default value of Persistence.Size(8Gi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case problem was related with droped IPtables FORWARD policy. I had investigated it with the help of "microk8s.inspect" command. InitContainer couldn't get access to the Internet and it stopped deployment of whole pod with main container. Solving was easy - "sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT" and redeployment with Helm.